# Verifying that a set is an algebra

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be an algebra on some set $X$.

Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be two finite measures defined on $\sigma(\mathcal{F})$ such that, $\forall A \in \mathcal{F}$, $\mu_1(A)=\mu_2(A)$.

Show that $\mathcal{M}= \lbrace A \in \sigma(\mathcal{F}) | \mu_1(A)=\mu_2(A) \rbrace$ is an algebra.

It's clear that $X\in \mathcal{M}$ and that $\mathcal{M}$ is closed under complementation. However, I am struggling to show that it is closed under finite unions (or intersections).

This is related to the question here: [Extending measure on Field to $\sigma$-Field](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3950924/extending-measure-on-field-to-sigma-field)

*Remkar:* In the book I'm learning from the $\pi$-$\lambda$ theorem is only covered in a later section. Thus, I'd like to find a proof that doesn't use this result.

Comment: Immediate application of $\pi -\lambda$ Theorem.

Comment: I have not covered that yet.

Comment: Why should it be closed under finite unions? Shouldn't it rather be countable union?

Comment: I only want to show that it is an algebra, not a sigma-algebra

Comment: Application of the Monotone Class Theorem requires that we show that it is an algebra first right?